# iphone Native Email Client UI

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have my own UI that renders email. but it renders only text mails. Now I am extending it to support HTML formatted mails. I wanted to know how Apple does it in native email client and then replicate the same in my App's UI. In particular, I am interested in knowing what UI component is used by the native email client to display the Mail body. All HTML text is rendered properly in it and also you are allowed to edit it. I am trying to replicate the same.

Answer (score 2):

use MFMailComposerViewController

Comment: No no what is inside that MFMailComposeViewController. How is it made?

Comment: it behave like model view controller . simply create the object of MFMailComposeViewController and add to navigation or View Controller . it will animate from down to up . and before adding MailViewController object we can set subject, messageBody , CC, TO , attached any file if require . and it open within native app. i hope it will help you

Comment: visit this link http://mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-2-in-app-email-messageui/

Answer (score 1):

@Bogus boy you have to use `MFMailComposeViewController` here is the best tutorial from the apple developers document which will give you every help regarding how to use it and how is it made with a tutorial....its a best one have a look at **[MailComposer from document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MailComposer/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008865-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_7)**. This is the way how we pass html..

```
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailView = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailView.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [mailView setSubject:@"Good Morning"];
    [mailView addAttachmentData: mimeType: fileName:];
    NSString *bodyString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<html><body>This is place where you place your HTML format</body></html>"];
    [mailView setMessageBody:bodyString isHTML:YES];

    [self presentModalViewController:mailView animated:YES];
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I have my own UI that renders email. My UI renders only text mails.  Now I am extending it to support HTML formatted mails. I wanted to know how Apple does it in native email client and then replicate the same in my Apps UI. In particular I am interested in knowing what UI component it is that the native email client uses to display Mail body. All HTML text is rendered properly in it and also you are allowed to edit it. I am trying to replicate that.

Comment: @Bogus boy i had edited my answer please refer to that....is that is something what you want